# Coding or converting grib files

Tags: c#, grib, fortran

I want to convert my text file to grib file. But it seems not possible. How can I code grib files in Fortran or C#.

Comment: have you tried the [wgrib2 Fortran API](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/wgrib2api.html)?

Answer (score 1):

There is so much library out there, that it is really a matter of preferences. The most complete, documented and up to date in my sense is [eccodes](https://confluence.ecmwf.int//display/ECC/Documentation), it offers C, Fortran and Python 2 bindings through a consistent API, and also provides prebuilt tool to quickly prototype features.
It also supports major other meteorological file formats such as BUFR and NetCDF.

If you are using an apt-based environnement, the easiest way to install the lib and its tool is by using your package manager (`apt-get install libeccodes0 libeccodes-tools`). If not you can still build it directly from source